# Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type int on android.widget.ImageView

Tags: android, android-databinding

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
}
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1"
```

In layout I have two images.

I want to set width **only** for first image.

Here is the XML layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <import type="com.myproject.android.customer.util.GuiUtil" />
    </data>
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@{GuiUtil.getTileWidthDpInScreen(context), default=@dimen/preview_image_height}"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"/>

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewFavorite"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"/>    

</layout>
```

Here is the adapter's code:

```
    @BindingAdapter("layout_width")
    public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, int width) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = width;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Here is the method `GuiUtil.getTileWidthDpInScreen`:

```
public class GuiUtil {    
    public static int getTileWidthDpInScreen(Context context) {
        // some logic that return int value
   }
```

But I get this error:

```
:app:transformDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type int on android.widget.ImageView.
file:myproject\app\src\main\res\layout\preview_offer_item.xml
loc:26:36 - 26:74
****\ data binding error ****    
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this syntax doesn't support with Android Databinding by default. You can use @BindingAdapter instead, here is full code below (Kotlin):

```
    @BindingAdapter("layoutWidth")
fun setLayoutWidth(layout: ViewGroup, dimen: Float) {
    val layoutParams = layout.layoutParams
    layoutParams.width = dimen.toInt()
    layout.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

in your XML layout file use "app:layoutWidth", you can use it even with additional syntax, e.g.:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"   //required
android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_102"   //required
app:layoutWidth="@{variable.predict ? @dimen/dp_86 : @dimen/dp_102}"
```

Comment: Shorter would even be to make it an extension function on ViewGroup like so:


```@BindingAdapter("layoutWidth")
fun ViewGroup.setLayoutWidth(dimen: Float) {
    layoutParams.Width = dimen.toInt()
}```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML It should be like this

```
app:layout_width="@{GuiUtil.getTileWidthDpInScreen(context), default=wrap_content}"
```

Comment: Not help. Error: `Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type float on android.widget.ImageView.`

Comment: You can use you same old line for Binding annotation `@BindingAdapter("layout_width")`

Comment: Not help: `error: attribute 'com.myproject.android.customer.debug:layout_width' not found.`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for your BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
```

Comment: Not help: I get error: `:app:kaptDebugKotlin
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type float on android.widget.ImageView.`

Comment: Did you change your BindingAdapter to accept a float instead of an int?

Comment: No. I'm not changed

Comment: Try changing to to accept a float instead of an int.

Comment: Yes, I set float and this help:  `@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
    public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, float width) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = (int) width;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`
    }

Answer (score 0):

adding: app:layoutWidth in layout with required values worked for me:
like:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
app:layoutWidth="@{testBoolean == true ? @dimen/value_1 : @dimen/value_2}"
```